# Calculating time & space complexity in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to calculate time and space complexity of a MATLAB code.Some built-in MATLAB functions like `imfilter`, `imread`, `fspecial`, `bwdist` are used in this code. So how can I calculate the time and space complexity of these built in functions or any code written in MATLAB? Anyone please help me.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] so we can take a look and try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not calculate it, the code is closed source and you can't make any theoretical assumptions on it. You can only address this empirical, run the function multiple times for different input sizes and get the values from the profiler.